# Why JavaCC Show Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javacc

I'm using JavaCC to build a simple language just for add and multiply of 2 or more variables. When I run code for example :  a+b  - error is shown

Was expecting one of:
    EOF  or "+" ..

My code is here

```
    SKIP :
{ " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" | "\r\n" }

TOKEN : 
{<PLUS:"+">
|<SHUMEZIM:"*">
|<id:(["a"-"z"])*>
| <lb:"(">
| <rb:")">
}

void Prog():
{}
{
   T() Ep() < EOF >
}


void Ep():
{}
{
( "+" Ep() )?
}

void T():
{}
{
  F() Tp()
}

void Tp():
{}
{
  ( "*" Tp() )?
}


void F():
{}
{
  "(" Prog() ")"
  | < id > 
}
```

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: smells like homework. show what you have tried and what your debugging showed. downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
void Ep():
{}
{
     ( "+" Ep() )?
}
```

should be

```
void Ep():
{}
{
     ( "+" T() )*
}
```

And likewise for `Tp`.